# Changing format on a variable via Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to make the 'date' variable in my 'register' table of my 'finances' database into a date format.

I have the following Python code which runs and does not throw any error. Everything works except the 'update register' statement.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\\SQLite\\finances.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor_obj = conn.cursor()

# read the csv file
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\SQLite\\finance_register.csv')

# write to SQLite
df.to_sql("register", conn, if_exists="replace", index=False)

# change column names
cursor.execute('''alter table register rename 'Category Group' to category_group''')
cursor.execute('''alter table register rename 'Account' to account''')
cursor.execute('''alter table register rename 'Flag' to flag''')
cursor.execute('''alter table register rename 'Date' to date''')
cursor.execute('''alter table register rename 'Payee' to payee''')
cursor.execute('''alter table register rename 'Category Group/Category' to category_group_category''')
cursor.execute('''alter table register rename 'Category' to category''')
cursor.execute('''alter table register rename 'Memo' to memo''')
cursor.execute('''alter table register rename 'Outflow' to outflow''')
cursor.execute('''alter table register rename 'Inflow' to inflow''')
cursor.execute('''alter table register rename 'Cleared' to cleared''')

cursor.execute('''update register set date = substr(date, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(date, 1, 2) || '-' || substr(date, 4, 2)''')
    
conn.close()
```

When I execute the following code in SQLite Studio, the changes take effect:

```
update register set date=substr(date, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(date, 1, 2) || '-' || substr(date, 4, 2);
```

I am unsure why the Python script is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite in Python implements transaction management ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#transaction-control)), which means that certain statements, namely `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`, and `REPLACE` implicitly open a [SQL transaction](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-transactions/) that has to be committed. Uncommited transactions are ignored.

While you can turn this off by passing the `isolation_level=None` keyword parameter to your `.connect()` function ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.isolation_level)), my recommendation would be to add a [`db.commit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#transaction-control) statement at the end of your program, as below.

```py
db.commit()

db.close()
```

You may also consider the [`db.executescript()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#transaction-control) function, which allows you to more easily call several SQL statements simultaneously.